Terminal input lag in ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I'm experiencing GNOME terminal input lag. I've tried solutions here that are supposed to work, but I still have terminal input lag.
Results of uname -r :
Linux hajiPC 6.5.0-44-generic #44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jun 18 14:36:16 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


Your details show you're well behind on applying security fixes; so I suggest you apply all fixes asap. The 6.5 kernel was from Ubuntu 23.10 which is EOL; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS using the HWE kernel stack upgraded to the 6.8 kernel, with GA remaining on 5.15.

I was uneducated about this. I wanted to switch to GA kernel, because updating the kernel always broke my patched nvidia driver. is following this answer a good practice ?

I'd just follow official instructions, ie. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack where you want the "To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:" ...   You can also have GA+HWE(+OEM) installed; however many NVidia kernel modules can prevent multiple kernel stacks from co-existing...  The answer you reference is using details & references the instructions I'd follow anyway.

@guiverc i had the time today to do it, i went to 5.15.0-122-generic GA kernel, and did a sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade but the terminal lag is still there. there i thought ubuntu has officially patched it ?
